# How to remove characters after specific word using grep command in BBEDIT?

Tags: grep, text

I have these data where I need to remove the extended URL from each website to make it, previously I used `^.+?(?=.com )` to remove the front line of characters. This time I need to remove the words after `.com`.

For example:

```
https://myamcap.com/calem-atkins/
```

then it will become

```
https://myamcap.com/
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "BBEDIT", but that looks like perl regexps in which case `\.com/?\K.*` might work at matching the part of the  line after the first occurrence of `.com` followed by an optional `/`.

Comment: Is the input just a list of URLs, one per line? Are there URLs with domains other than `.com` that should be left unaltered?  Are you looking for a solution that you can apply from within BBEdit, or would a command-line solution also work?

Answer (score -1):

this will only get the first part of the url:

```
grep -Po '^(.*://[^/]+)/' textfile
```

Comment: Not for general URLs (`ftp` protocol, top levels other than `com`, absolute domain names, etc).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. edited to support general urls and any top level.